# How to use an option of FullSimplify on Mathematica or something similar

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I solved an equation and now I have this solution but I want to have everything more simple or at least just on Arc or Log! but I can't make them more simple!

`FullSimplify[-((2 m ArcTanh[(m x)/Sqrt[-f+(b+m^2) x^2]]+m Log[f-b x^2]-2 Sqrt[b+m^2] Log[b x+m^2 x+Sqrt[b+m^2] Sqrt[-f+(b+m^2) x^2]])/(2 b)),Assumptions->{m>0,b>0,f>0,x>0}]`

Comment: `expr = -((2 m ArcTanh[(m x)/Sqrt[-f + (b + m^2) x^2]] + 
       m Log[f - b x^2] - 
       2 Sqrt[b + m^2] Log[
         b x + m^2 x + 
          Sqrt[b + m^2] Sqrt[-f + (b + m^2) x^2]])/(2 b));` and `Simplify[TrigToExp[expr], Assumptions -> {m > 0, b > 0, f > 0, x > 0}]` ?

Comment: Exactly I wanted this but the problem is now there is a lot of Log[] how to make them joint together?

Comment: This term "-f + (b + m^2) x^2 " is everywhere how to one change of the variable I can make them more simple?

Comment: I used this but it is not showing anything

1/(2 b) (-m Log[f - b x^2] + 
    m Log[1 - (m x)/Sqrt[-f + (b + m^2) x^2]] - 
    m Log[1 + (m x)/Sqrt[-f + (b + m^2) x^2]] + 
    2 Sqrt[b + m^2]
      Log[(b + m^2) x + 
       Sqrt[(b + m^2) (-f + (b + m^2) x^2)]]) /. -f + (b + m^2) x -> 
  Sin[\[Theta]]

Comment: Try `Simplify[1/(2 b)(-m Log[f-b x^2]+m Log[1-(m x)/Sqrt[-f+(b+m^2)x^2]]-m Log[1+(m x)/Sqrt[-f+(b+m^2)x^2]]+2 Sqrt[b+m^2]Log[(b+m^2)x+Sqrt[(b+m^2)(-f+(b+m^2)x^2)]]),-f+(b+m^2)x==st]` If that mostly works then you can substitute `Sin[Theta]` for st.

Comment: Hi Bill, My question now is it possible to change the Log[] to Tanh[] ??